# Independence with p.d.f

Tags: probability-theory

In Durrett's probability theory book, it says

> Suppose $(X_1,\dots, X_n)$ has density $f(x_1,\dots,x_n)$. If $f(x)$ can be written as $g_1(x_1)\dots g_n(x_n)$ where $g_m(x_m)\ge 0$ are measurable, then $X_1,\dots,X_n$ are independent. $g_m$ are not assumed to be probability densities.

If $g_m$ are probability densities, I can show, by Fubini's theorem, $$P((X_1,\dots,X_n)\in A)=\int_A f(x)\;dx = \int_{A_1}g_1(x_1)\;dx_1 \dots \int_{A_n}g_n(x_n)\;dx_n=\prod P(X_i \in A_i)$$

But $g_m$ are not assumed to be probability densities. Although I can normalize it by $$h_m(x)=\frac{g_m(x)}{\int_R g_m(x_m)\;dx_m},$$ I don't have $$\int_{A_m}h_m(x_m)\;dx_m=P(X_m \in A_m).$$

I'm not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first define 
$$
c_m= \int_\mathbb R g_m(x)\; dx.
$$
Then you have that 
\begin{align}
P(X_m \in A) &= P( X_m \in A, \ X_i \in \mathbb R, \ i\neq m) = \prod_{i \neq m}c_i \cdot \int_A g_m(x) \; dx \\
&= \int_A \prod_{i \neq m}c_i \cdot g_m(x) \; dx.
\end{align}
So the denistiy of $X_m$ is given by $ \prod_{i \neq m}c_i \cdot g_m(x)$ and everything works fine.
$ \prod_{i \neq m}c_i$ is the normalizing constant for $g_m$.